# What does "third west" mean in hospital?

Tags: grammar

> Go to **third west**.

When a nurse or someone says this to you in a hospital context, what does this mean to you?

Comment: Don't hurry in selecting answer. You may get different perspectives and more clarification with various answers to your question. Just wait and get more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but I'd assume this means go to the third floor of the west wing.

Comment: Also, this isn't hospital-specific -- any large multi-wing building can have a shortened floor naming thing like this.

Answer (score 2):

Hospitals normally have "wings", which are areas of the building that are located geographically from the main part of the building, and sometimes are named accordingly. So "third west" means:

> Third **floor**, **west** wing.